# How to install vue using snap

Tags: snap

I am trying to [Install vue on Ubuntu using the Snap Store](https://snapcraft.io/install/vue/ubuntu).

`sudo snap install vue` works fine, but when I try to run vue i get:

```
(base) ntg@my-pc:~$ vue
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
Error: Unable to access jarfile /snap/vue/1/jar/vue-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Any way to fix this/install vue from a snap? I know I can use npm or yarn, this question is about using snaps

Also, any thoughts on what this error means / pointers on what may be the problem will be appreciated...

Comment: That snap is broken and not trivially fixable, I'm afraid. I'd uninstall it or contact the publisher and ask them to fix it. I have rebuilt it and have it semi-working here, but the publisher needs to fix it really.

Comment: That is an issue with snap: regularly, you encounter snaps that are broken.